# Sql Server to Oracle - Change procedures and view syntax

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-migration

I have this procedurein sql server that does this logic of calculating dates and return this information for application, but unfortunately I will have to switch to an oracle database, so I would like your help to know what I have to change in syntax.

P.S: Never used oracle database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ObterDadosApontamentosOperacional]
@dataInicio as dateTime = null,
@dataFim as datetime = null,
@embarcacaoId as varchar(50) = null

AS
BEGIN

if(@dataInicio is null)
begin
    set @dataInicio = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
end

if(@dataFim is null)
begin
    set @dataFim = (DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0)) +1)
end


select 
    codigoOperacao.Id           as 'Id',
    codigoOperacao.Descricao    as 'Descricao',
    codigoOperacao.Codigo       as 'CodigoOperacao',
    count(codigoOperacao.Codigo) as 'TotalUnitario'
into #parcial
from INFO_APONTAMENTO as apontamento
inner join CODIGOS_OPERACAO as codigoOperacao on codigoOperacao.Id = apontamento.CodigosDeOperacao_Id
where apontamento.DataCadastro between @dataInicio and @dataFim
and ((apontamento.Barco_Id = @embarcacaoId) or @embarcacaoId is null)

group by
    codigoOperacao.Codigo,
    codigoOperacao.Descricao,
    codigoOperacao.Id   


/*--------------------------------------------*/

   select 
        Id,
        Descricao,
        CodigoOperacao  ,
        DataInicio  ,   
        DataTermino ,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DataInicio,DataTermino)
    into #tempApontamentosPorHora
    from #tempApontamentos
    where DataInicio is not null
    and DataTermino is not null

declare @somaTotal as int = (select     sum(totalUnitario) from #parcial)
select *, @somaTotal as TotalAgregado from #parcial
```

end

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Oracle SQL Developer, it has a translator built in.

Here's what it tries to do with your T-SQL

```
/*Global Temporary Tables:2 *//* Translation Extracted DDL For Required Objects*/
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_parcial
AS (
   SELECT codigoOperacao.Id Id  ,
   codigoOperacao.Descricao Descricao  ,
   codigoOperacao.Codigo CodigoOperacao  ,
   0  TotalUnitario  
     FROM INFO_APONTAMENTO apontamento
     JOIN CODIGOS_OPERACAO codigoOperacao   ON codigoOperacao.Id = apontamento.CodigosDeOperacao_Id
   WHERE 1=2
);
/
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_tempApontamentosPorHora
AS (
   SELECT Id ,
   Descricao ,
   CodigoOperacao ,
   DataInicio ,
   DataTermino ,
   utils.datediff('MINUTE', DataInicio, DataTermino) 
     FROM tt_tempApontamentos
   WHERE 1=2
);
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ObterDadosApontamentosOperacional
(
  iv_dataInicio IN DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
  iv_dataFim IN DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_embarcacaoId IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL 
)
AS
   v_dataInicio DATE := iv_dataInicio;
   v_dataFim DATE := iv_dataFim;
   v_somaTotal NUMBER(10,0) := ( SELECT SUM(totalUnitario)  
     FROM tt_parcial  );
   v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
   IF ( v_dataInicio IS NULL ) THEN

   BEGIN
      v_dataInicio := utils.dateadd('DAY', utils.datediff('DAY', 0, SYSDATE), 0) ;

   END;
   END IF;
   IF ( v_dataFim IS NULL ) THEN

   BEGIN
      v_dataFim := (utils.dateadd('MS', -3, utils.dateadd('DD', utils.datediff('DD', 0, SYSDATE), 0)) + 1) ;

   END;
   END IF;
   DELETE FROM tt_parcial;
   UTILS.IDENTITY_RESET('tt_parcial');

   INSERT INTO tt_parcial ( 
    SELECT codigoOperacao.Id Id  ,
           codigoOperacao.Descricao Descricao  ,
           codigoOperacao.Codigo CodigoOperacao  ,
           COUNT(codigoOperacao.Codigo)  TotalUnitario  
      FROM INFO_APONTAMENTO apontamento
             JOIN CODIGOS_OPERACAO codigoOperacao   ON codigoOperacao.Id = apontamento.CodigosDeOperacao_Id
     WHERE  apontamento.DataCadastro BETWEEN v_dataInicio AND v_dataFim
              AND ( ( apontamento.Barco_Id = v_embarcacaoId )
              OR v_embarcacaoId IS NULL )
      GROUP BY codigoOperacao.Codigo,codigoOperacao.Descricao,codigoOperacao.Id );
   /*--------------------------------------------*/
   DELETE FROM tt_tempApontamentosPorHora;
   UTILS.IDENTITY_RESET('tt_tempApontamentosPorHora');

   INSERT INTO tt_tempApontamentosPorHora ( 
    SELECT Id ,
           Descricao ,
           CodigoOperacao ,
           DataInicio ,
           DataTermino ,
           utils.datediff('MINUTE', DataInicio, DataTermino) 
      FROM tt_tempApontamentos 
     WHERE  DataInicio IS NOT NULL
              AND DataTermino IS NOT NULL );
   OPEN  v_cursor FOR
      SELECT * ,
             v_somaTotal TotalAgregado  
        FROM tt_parcial  ;
      DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cursor);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN utils.handleerror(SQLCODE,SQLERRM);
END;
```

I'm not saying that this is your IDEAL answer or even THE answer, but the feature is there to help you get a running start.

One big thing from SQL Server to Oracle - a lot of SQL Server stored procs I see are just queries to be ran.

Oracle Stored Procedures aren't setup to be just 'dumb' SQL statements. It's meant to process data. So one thing you have to do if you don't want the behavior to change, your application will need go GET the results of your procedure, there's no run code, get query results back when working with PL/SQL.

This is a bit easier in [12c and higher versions of Oracle where we have added support for implicit results](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/drdaa/sql-translation-and-migration-guide.pdf), but you'll have to add a call to DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT to get them.